# Cycle.js Nested HTTP Requests

Tags: cyclejs

I'm trying to send multiple HTTP requests using the cycle-http driver.  The first request in my example grabs a list of mailboxes and out of that response are multiple mailboxes I have to send HTTP requests for subsequent threads.

Get all mailbox IDs HTTP request -> Get all mail from each mailbox HTTP request.

I'm pretty stumped at this point, all the examples I have seen are simple single requests where the url is known prior to generating the observable.  So not only am I confused about nesting HTTP requests, but I also am not sure how to "know" the URL for a `filter` after the request has been made since the URLs are generated dynamically.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can assume we already have a stream representing the results from the first "level" of HTTP requests. We can simply map over these results and transform them to new HTTP requests:

```
// this should be sent to HTTP driver
let mailboxDetailsRequests$ = mailboxes$.map(mailboxes => {
  // map all mailboxes to requests sequence
  return Observable.fromArray(mailboxes.map(mailbox => ({
    url: 'get/mailbox/url/' + mailbox.name,
    mailbox: mailbox.name
  }))
}).flatMap(_ => _)
```

Now we can access these HTTP responses by filtering on the `mailbox` property of the request (or you can use some sort of distinguishing feature that separates these requests from other types):

```
// and now you can get the responses by filtering the HTTP source
let mailboxResult$ = HTTP.filter(r$$ => r$$.request.mailbox).switch();
```

Comment: do you think it's better to use flatMap instead of switch when creating mailboxDetailsRequests if we are sure that there is only one request to retrieve all mail boxes?

Comment: Yes flatMap should be used.